# Set up Python tkTable

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, tktable

Being very new to Phyton, I’m trying to use tktable for Python and can’t get it run on my PC.
After searching a lot in the net, without finding any solution, I hope you find the time to help me a bit.
I’m sure this is peanuts for you.

I’m running Python 3.7 on a Windows 8.1. PC.

I’m getting this error:

> _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "table"

What I did so far:

1. Downloaded tktable and run the setup.py.
2. Copied the tktable.py to the Python site-packages folder.
3. Installed ActiveTcl.
4. Copied the three files tktable.tcl, Tktable.dll and pkgIndex.tcl from ActiveTcl (C:\ActiveTcl\lib\Tktable2.11) to C:........\Python\Python37-32\tcll\Tktable2.11.
5. According what I have found in the net, this should do it…

But, as I wrote, I keep getting the error I mentioned.

Michael

The content is:

```
C:\Users\mschuppisser.EAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\;
C:\Users\mschuppisser.EAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\
```

> Traceback:
>
> ```
> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\mschuppisser.EAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)
>   File "C:/Users/mschuppisser.EAD/Data/My Data/Python/Test Applikation/Test Applikation.py", line 267, in Jump_to_UebersichtsFenster3
>     application = clsUebersichtsFenster3(UebersichtsFenster3)
>   File "C:/Users/mschuppisser.EAD/Data/My Data/Python/Test Applikation/Test Applikation.py", line 447, in __init__
>     self.table_grid = tktable.Table(UebersichtsFenster3) # , state='disabled', width=50, titlerows=1, rows=5, cols=4, colwidth=20)
>   File "C:\Users\mschuppisser.EAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tktable.py", line 135, in __init__
>     tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, 'table', kw)
>   File "C:\Users\mschuppisser.EAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
>     (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
> _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "table"
> ```

Comment: No `\tcl` path. Edit your Question and show the **Full Traceback**. Are you familiar with [They go into Python folder like so:](http://blog.clintecker.com/post/148453368/tktable-for-tkinter-and-python). `C:\Python2.x` becomes your `C:...\Python\Python37-32`

Comment: Thx for the idea @stovfl!
I tried both, adding the \tcl to the list in regedit and moving the Tktable.dll file to the DDL folder.
Same error…….
Any other idea?

Comment: Yes @stovfl, I have C:\ActiveTcl\lib\Tktable2.11. It's the same as C:\Users\mschuppisser.EAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\tcl\Tktable2.11.

Comment: This is my full traceback.
Will go through 'They go into Python folder like so' next week. I'm in Project work at the moment. Thx for your support @stovfl!

Comment: Hi @stovfl
Ok, had time to spend a few minutes on this issue besides project work.
The .dll and the two tcls are in Tktable2.11. This is simply the newer version of 2.7. At least the original folders name was 2.11 too.
Lib.lib-tk I had to create and moved the thtable.py there.
My program didn’t recognize this folder a a lib, so I added it in the code using sys.path.insert(0, …..).
Now it finds the module but still failing with the same error.
Oddly it created a .egg file… hope this is ok.
Cheers
Michael

Comment: The error is **not** about `tktable.py`, this is the Python `tkinter` part, `lib/lib-tk` looks OK. The error is not finding or loading `Tktable.dll`. What's the point here, **NOT** using **only** the `ActiveTcl` distribution?

Comment: Hi stovfl
I don't get you. I have copied the three ActiveTcl files from ist original place to the Python tcl folder. Path is C:\.......\Python\Python37-32\tcl\Tktable2.11.

Comment: Your path `C:\...Python\Python37-32\tcl\Tktable2.11` looks OK. Sorry, the name is [activestate.com/products/activepython/](https://www.activestate.com/products/activepython/)

Comment: Hi stovfl 
I don't see how this link can help me with my Python tkTable problem. Unless you think this Teapot tool can help me?
Cheers
Michael

Comment: Hi @stovfl, done: https://github.com/SchuppiM/Python-tkTable/blob/master/tkTable%20Problem